# how to have a shared assembly folder in a c# application

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

When I deploy and application, there is normally a bin folder that has my referenced dlls, or the referenced dlls are in the same folder. I would like to create a shared folder that contains dlls that would be re-used by other applications on a single computer.

Do not wish to use the GAC, I would like to be able to copy and past, to update the dlls over continually registering/de-registering on the GAC. Is there a way to place this on a folder?

Comment: Are you talking about where the built assemblies are placed after successful build?  Post-build event with a command to copy select assebllies to a shared folder might work.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use the GAC? This is pretty much what it's there for, so your reasoning might clarify extra requirements. Currently, this will be difficult - the Fusion assembly binder looks in a fixed set of paths (loosely, GAC and application folder), and I'm not aware of a way to change that (although, to be fair, I've never looked!)

Comment: @MattC I'm talking about deployment of an application. It seems like there are specific places where an application looks for dlls, I would like to be able to configure that

Comment: I would love to know y I got a -1

Comment: @David possibly someone else decided the question wasn't clear enough to be of use to others.  Maybe try and reword it?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN:Deploying Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164080.aspx) looks like what I'm looking for... just need to test a little

Private dll